Connect the Dymo web service with Angular
I want to connect the Dymo web service with my Angular app.
I have downloaded the file from here. and added to assets Dymo
For that I have added this code in angular.json file.
"scripts": [
              {
                "input": "src/assets/js/dymo.connect.framework.js",
                "bundleName": "dymo"
              }
            ],

I have made dymo.d.ts file in assets/js and wrote declare module 'dymo'
Then in component I have declare the variable as :
dymo: any = dymo
Now on ngOnInit function I am getting the suggestion for dymo.label.framework.
in that suggestion I am not getting the init function first of all.
and when I try to compile the project error comes like cannot find name 'dymo'
If I write window['dymo'].label.framework.VERSION; then it says Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
